# How to open .saz websocket dump?

Tags: fiddler

I know .saz files are just a zip archive.
However, when i try to open websocket session file (the .w file in .saz)
most of values are in unknown binary format. How i can read them? when i view same .saz file in fiddler, it works well (i see normal text data from websocket session). But when i open it in notepad i get the following:

```
‚ю —Ѓ]CИСњЎr0ја)6»ЎњСrrж°PIЂо.7тЎ/0жв<1Єо3$©м80жв2.Е‹0­уpЇд37тЎ,§кfqюІisуП< ¤·icЕ‹,¦х8-ј¬   :ёдgc©с-/Ўв<7Ўо3l°¬*4ї¬;,ємp6єн8-«о9&¬ЊW §п)&¦хp­п:7 »}sЕ‹PI
Request-Length: 17
ID: 17
BitFlags: 0
DoneRead: 2015-02-14T09:47:35.1427680+03:00
BeginSend: 2015-02-14T09:47:35.1427680+03:00
DoneSend: 2015-02-14T09:47:35.1427680+03:00
```

How i can decode this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSocket file's format is not currently documented and direct manipulation is not supported.

As of Fiddler 2.5.0.1, the format is as follows:

```
[File Headers]\r\n
[Message 0 Headers]\r\n
[Message 0 raw bytes]\r\n
[Message 1 Headers]\r\n
[Message 1 raw bytes]\r\n
[Message 2 Headers]\r\n
[Message 3 raw bytes]\r\n
<eof>
```

Obviously, parsing this requires that you have code that can parse the raw bytes of a WebSocket message.

Rather than writing all of that code yourself, you'd probably be better off just using Fiddler's Script or Extension model to interact with the `WebSocketMessage` objects that Fiddler builds when reloading a SAZ file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! can you point me out how to decode the raw message itself?